# Bat файл не сохраняет в файл результат работы программы

Tags: windows, bat

Не знаком с bat-файлами, но с помощью интернета сваял скриптик. Данная комада через cmd работает корректно `e:\server\mysql-5.7.24\bin\mysqldump.exe" -uroot mybase > e:\sql.sql`, но если запустить bat-файл, создается пустой файл `mybase_2019-01-15_13-11-35.sql`.

Вычитал, что бат пишет в файл то, что выводится на экран. Так на экран и выводится, то что должно быть в файле дампа бд.

Пробовал и от имени администратора, пусто.

Код батника:

```
set date=%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
start "" "e:\server\mysql-5.7.24\bin\mysqldump.exe" -uroot mybase  > e:\mybase_%date%.sql
exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы перенаправили в файл вывод команды start, а надо было перенаправить вывод mysqldump...

К сожалению, start не умеет перенаправлять ввод-вывод, поэтому для перенаправления вам нужно запустить cmd еще раз в отдельном окне, и не забыть экранировать символ `>`:

```
start "" cmd /c "e:\server\mysql-5.7.24\bin\mysqldump.exe" -uroot mybase  ^> e:\mybase_%date%.sql
```

Однако, прежде чем писать такого монстра, убедитесь что вам вообще нужна команда start. Обычно ее используют чтобы основной файл мог продолжить выполнение, а у вас там дальше exit стоит. Возможно, вот так будет проще:

```
"e:\server\mysql-5.7.24\bin\mysqldump.exe" -uroot mybase  > e:\mybase_%date%.sql
```

Comment: догадывался как раз об этом, что не то направлено в вывод, сенкс.