# mysqldump не экспортирует данные

Tags: mysql, windows

Делаю бекапы [подобным методом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/932345/bat-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B), создан bat-файл с командой

```
"e:\server\mysql-5.7.24\bin\mysqldump.exe" -uroot mybase  > e:\mybase_%date%.sql
```

Но однажды заглянув внутрь файла заметил, что бекап не содержит в себе данные, только строки

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `batch`;
CREATE TABLE `batch` (
LOCK TABLES `batch` WRITE;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Строки `INSERT INTO` отстуствуют. Запускал батник и от имени администратора, то же самое. Виндовс 8. Phpmyadmin экспортирует нормально.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А `UAC` включен?

Comment: @donRumata вывод UAC уведомлений настроен на самый минимум. То есть получается отключен.

Comment: А если демона стопнуть и потом запустить бэкап?

Comment: @donRumata пардон, при детальном рассмотрении файла обнаружил, что бекап создан был, просто первые таблицы были пустые, а все инсерты выстроены в одну строку, поэтому файл визуально был маленький.

Comment: @donRumata а панику я поднял после того, как после импорта из файла в базу данных ничего не произошло, сейчас с этим буду разбираться.

Comment: Ну т.е. и файл был по весу маленький?

Comment: @donRumata да, phpmyadmin 12 мег, mysqldump 7 мегабайт

Comment: в общем разобрался, восстановление бекапа "e:\server\mysql-5.7.24\bin\mysql.exe" -uroot mybase  < e:\mybase.sql